# get datetime value from datagridview cells and change it to persian date at run time

Tags: c#

I have a problem in `DataGridView` .
I fill `DataGridView` with a datable .
there are two columns that get date time value in `DataGridView` I want to change this value to Persian Date at run time what should I do?

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could fill another  `DataTable` by using [`PersianCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Persian date 1");
table.Columns.Add("Persian date 2");

var persCal = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable1.Rows)
{
    DateTime dt1 = row.Field<DateTime>(0);
    DateTime dt2 = row.Field<DateTime>(1);
    int year1 = persCal.GetYear(dt1);
    int month1 = persCal.GetMonth(dt1);
    int day1 = persCal.GetDayOfMonth(dt1);
    int year2 = persCal.GetYear(dt2);
    int month2 = persCal.GetMonth(dt2);
    int day2 = persCal.GetDayOfMonth(dt2);
    string persDate1 = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", year1, month1, day1);
    string persDate2 = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", year2, month2, day2);
    table.Rows.Add(persDate1, persDate2);
}
```

Then use this as datasource.